# Suppress "No Source Available" pane in 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vsx, vspackage

Arg!  I have a custom "harness" executable running my class library project.  Every time I step into the harness's code, I get that "No Source Available" pane popping up.  As I know there is no source available, and that this is completely expected, I don't want this very intrusive and useless pane popping up every time.  How can I suppress it completely?

I can make it smaller at least by making that window part of another smaller pane-set, such as with the watches/locals.  It remembers its location from run to run, but its still useless.

There might be a more general answer to this question - how can I suppress any particular pane/window from showing at all?  I have a VSX package, originally built for VS 2008 (and must keep that compatibility) but I just don't know what command to run to do it.  (I had the package commissioned, so I have the source, but not the know-how.  This seems like a one/two liner).

Thanks!

Comment: Update: I tried that tiny install from Visual Studio Gallery (linked below) and that worked, hooray! Mucho recommended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After finding no help on this, I dug in to it myself and fixed it by Hiding the WindowFrame in the event that it is shown.  There is no visual refresh glitch that I've seen so far.

Here is the GUID for the "No Source Available" pane:  `{1820bae5-c385-4492-9de5-e35c9cf17b18}`

I found most of what I needed from this post:

http://blogs.msdn.com/dr._ex/archive/2004/11/07/253601.aspx

I believe this will only affect solutions with this package loaded, but really I don't know if the package stays loaded/active if the related project is closed.

Comment: Can you provide more details what you did? I didn't quite understand

Comment: That's a broad question.  Can you be more specific about your scenario?  Maybe ask a brand new question and then post a link in a comment below - and link to this one for the new one as background?

Comment: I think he's asking, "can you provide some details about what you did?" I didn't quite understand either. Something about a GUID and hiding windowFrames when they're shown. Sounds like gibberish to a plebe such as myself.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a link to an add-in that correct the bug:

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/fdbb2036-471e-40a7-b20e-31f8fd5578fa

This work great for me.

Comment: This worked! This is the answer! Upside-down dude, please mark this as the answer, much obliged.

Comment: Not *the* answer for my question since mine is about fixing it for the users of the VSX package - implicitly *without* such a dependency.  It is a good answer though and I'm sure people will appreciate finding it.

Comment: I see. It was the answer for me and I got all excited and such.

Comment: Link is broken. What is the name of the extension? Could it be https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mayerwin.DisableNoSourceAvailableTab

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

`Tools > Options > Debugging` and **untick** `Enable Just My Code`

(thanks to [this](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/552550/cannot-suppress-no-source-available-window))

Answer (score 3):

If you have enabled source server support, the solution is here: [No Source available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2806993/no-source-available)

Comment: Where does this link address suppressing the No Source Available pane?

Comment: Clarified. The add-in is probably a better solution though.