# No Source available

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging

I am not sure what happened or if I did anything..
Now anytime I try and debug it says no source available on all BCL stuff
For example,  on a debug.print I get that message with

> Locating source for
>   'f:\dd\ndp\fx\src\CompMod\System\Diagnostics\Debug.cs'.
>   Checksum: MD5 {40 74 18 44 a8 15 28 2e
>   54 75 5e 40 d1 5f 6a 0}
>
> The file
>   'f:\dd\ndp\fx\src\CompMod\System\Diagnostics\Debug.cs'
>   does not exist.
>
> Looking in script documents for
>   'f:\dd\ndp\fx\src\CompMod\System\Diagnostics\Debug.cs'...
>
> Looking in the projects for
>   'f:\dd\ndp\fx\src\CompMod\System\Diagnostics\Debug.cs'.
>   The file was not found in a project.
>
> Looking in directory 'C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   10.0\VC\crt\src\'...
>
> Looking in directory 'C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   10.0\VC\atlmfc\src\mfc\'...
>
> Looking in directory 'C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   10.0\VC\atlmfc\src\atl\'...
>
> Looking in directory 'C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   10.0\VC\atlmfc\include\'...
>
> The debug source files settings for
>   the active solution indicate that the
>   debugger will not ask the user to find
>   the file:
>   f:\dd\ndp\fx\src\CompMod\System\Diagnostics\Debug.cs.
>
> The debugger could not locate the
>   source file
>   'f:\dd\ndp\fx\src\CompMod\System\Diagnostics\Debug.cs'.

This happens all the time now and I:

1. Don't have an F:
2. Enable .net framework source stepping is unchecked

Is there some other sneaky setting to make these messages go away?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

`f:\dd\ndp\fx\src\...` is the path to the source file on the machine that the .Net Framework was compiled on.

Go to Tools, Options, Debugging, Symbols, and select Only specified modules.
Also, uncheck Enable source server support in Debugging/General.

Comment: thanks I checked and Enable source server support was/is unchecked and only specified modules was/is selected. It appears that the only way for this to stop happening is to enable "Just My Code" and those messages go away. I noticed when I installed the Ants suite it disabled that. Is that normal functionality?

Comment: Try emptying your symbol cache.

Answer (score 4):

In Visual Studio 2010, I had to go to Tools\Options\Debugging\Just-In-Time and uncheck "Managed"|

Answer (score 4):

Go to `Tools`, `Options`, `Debugging`, `Symbols` and select `Only specified modules`.
It worked for me.

[image: debugging symbols options]

Answer (score 0):

I have also seen this when somehow one of the projects in a solution has its build option in configuration manager unset. If you see this, go to the Build menu, Configuration Manager, then make sure the affected projects have the Build option checked.

Answer (score 0):

Also click on the BUILD>configuration manager, make sure the 'Configuration' tab is set to debug for your project and not release.