# No source available when debuggin ninject

Tags: ninject

I have same the problem as here [No Source Available Error With Ninject When Debugging Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8506618/no-source-available-error-with-ninject-when-debugging-code)

Checking "Tools/Options/Debug/Just my code" makes absolutely no difference at all.

The error appears when debugger steps out from class below:

```
class TestModule : Ninject.Modules.NinjectModule {
    public override void Load() {
        Bind<IWeapon>().To<Sword>();
        Bind<IWeapon>().To<Dagger>();
    }
}
```

I installed Ninject yesterday using 'Add library package reference' in VS2010

Comment: possible duplicate of [No Source Available Error With Ninject When Debugging Code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8506618/no-source-available-error-with-ninject-when-debugging-code)

Comment: Yes, but none of the suggested tips work. Not the 'Just my code' nor downloading again using nuGet.

Comment: Get the sourcecode and point VS to it, delete pdb, all options are there. It is not a Ninject issue but a how do I correctly use VS question. So better ask using the VS tag.

Comment: Thanks Remo, you think this is a specific problem of my environment? I can't imagine thousands of ninject users having to download source since due not working nuGet package
Sorry für mi grotteschlächts Änglisch ;-)

Comment: The NuGet package works perfectly. It seems that Ninject throws an exception, most likely due to a configuration problem. E.g. no binding or a duplicated binding. VS breaks at the point where the exception is thrown inside Ninject because it has the pdb and asks you for the source code because it does not find it. I intensionally added the pdb that users have the option to debug into Ninject. But this means you have to grab the source code. Or as I told you can delete the pdb's which should result in VS break in your code when an exception occurs.

Comment: Thanks for ultrafast answering Remo. I got no exception, code works fine..just wondering why I got that messag when stepping out of mentionend method. Nevermind I'll grab the source

Comment: No difference after deleting pdb nor setting 'just my code'.No difference when using sourcecode, except annoying 'no source code available' is not popping up anymore.

Comment: Sorry..I hit 'enter' too fast. Will come up with more details soon