# missing NinjectDependancyResolver.cs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dll, ninject

i'm working on a project that uses mvc in dotnet. i have to develop the remaining code given to me.I made a copy of the Maincode and tried to run it ;i'm getting this error when i tried to run with breakpoints.
This is the error i'm getting.
i googled and i got a answer saying to refresh the reference  i did that too, but its not helping. what can be the problem.

this is the error i'm getting, a screen shot from web.

http://www.google.co.in/imgres?um=1&sa=N&hl=en&biw=1024&bih=621&tbm=isch&tbnid=MuZffsIBSR3nhM:&imgrefurl=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8506618/no-source-available-error-with-ninject-when-debugging-code&docid=yGGstg8JC99hAM&imgurl=https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlWbT.png&w=1107&h=480&ei=GotmUf2yNYWKrgeam4DYBw&zoom=1&ved=1t:3588,r:3,s:0,i:91&iact=rc&dur=1437&page=1&tbnh=148&tbnw=341&start=0&ndsp=12&tx=91&ty=96

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure your reference to Niniject in web project references is OK? Because it seems like  author of the code used sources of ninject (placed in c:\projects\ninject\...) instead of library or nuget package (i dont know why). Try remove that reference and add Ninject as nuget package and see what happens.

Comment: No, Its in another location. i removed and used "Add Reference" to add the dll again, but still its showing same error.