# Original Location of source files is incorrect

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have recently downloaded this: https://github.com/nhibernate/NHibernate.AspNet.Identity/tree/master/source/NHibernate.AspNet.Web

I can run it.  However, I cannot step through the code properly because I get a message like this on every line:

[image]

I realise that the original developer has obviously used the path (in original location) below.  I do not even have an F drive.  How can I correct the path?

I have read various questions on here and I have tried:

1) Cleaning and rebuilding

2) Deleting files from Debug and Release folders

3) Delete .suo

Comment: Did you rebuild the project?

Comment: @STLDeveloper.  Please see point one in my question.  Yes I did.

Comment: Sorry - should have asked "Did you successfully rebuild the project?".  Thanks.

Comment: @STLDeveloper, yes I did.

Comment: You said you "downloaded" it. Does that mean you downloaded the zip file instead of cloning it?

Comment: @NightOwl888, yes I think so.  What is the difference.

Comment: @w0051977 - Its possible the process that creates the zip file uses this path as a temp location and it is somehow bleeding through when you unzip it on your local system. I checked the project file and it is not referencing an `F` drive at all, so I suspect this could be why you are getting these errors.

Comment: @NightOwl888, is there anything I can do?

Comment: @w0051977 - Yes, try using `git clone` to get the project.

Comment: @NightOwl888, what do you mean by bleed?

Comment: @w0051977 - I have noticed that when you unzip applications from 3rd party sources, sometimes problems like these exist. I suspect it has something to do with the file attributes being set and/or file permissions when using certain zip libraries. You can avoid any such problems by cloning the repository directly using Git rather than using Zip.

Comment: @NightOwn888, SLaks answer here resolved my issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2806993/no-source-available