# String.cs cannot be located during DUMP file debug

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, dump

I built a windows service that has been running fine for some months now.  All of a sudden it keeps crashing.  I have my server admin generate a DUMP file for me to debug to see where the issue is.  In the DUMP summary I get the following Exception Information:

> The thread tried to read from or write to a virtual address for which it does not have the appropriate access.

When I attempt to DEBUG I get the following error:

> The debugger could not locate the source file 'f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\string.cs'.

The Call Stack shows:

> mscorlib.dll!string.Concat(string str0, string str1) Line 3207
>   C# Symbols loaded.

Could someone point me into the right direction?  I have seen other questions on this but they seem more geared towards custom user generated code like user controls.  This is a system file.

**EDIT**

Adding Photos

***Call Stack***
[image: Call Stack]
***Source Not Found***
[image: Source Not Found]

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2806993/no-source-available . If this would be not a `String` from `CLR` but some 3rd party dll, then e.g. `ILSpy` could generate `pdb` out of a `dll`

Comment: Yeah I found that one before.  Following those suggestions I only now get prompt for the location of string.cs rather than it just stopping.  And no, this is not a third party reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first thing of note, which I did not know, is that the .pdb file in the bin folder should be the same version as the current running application.  I had since made alterations to the source code after deployment so my subsequent builds altered the pdb file.

Second, since the debugger gave me the option to locate the file, I decided to go the the .NET repository, download the String.cs code, save it to a file on my drive and pointed to that file.